# How can I call Method.invoke with an arbitrary number of arguments?

Tags: java, parsing, methods, reflection, invoke

I am building a system in which the user can type names of methods into a text file, and a java program will parse it, invoking methods in a separate class corresponding to the method name typed. The user also types all the arguments to the method in the file. Using Class.getMethods, I know the type and number of arguments that the desired method takes. I do not know how to call Method.invoke with the correct number of arguments given the number of arguments the method takes (which could be any number).
Thanks in advance

Comment: `Method.getParameterTypes()`

Answer (score 2):

Supply an `Object[]` array as the second argument of Method.invoke.

`...` is syntactic sugar for an array of that type, and is how the called method actually receives the values.

Inversely, this can be problematic if you actually want to supply an `Object[]` to the method, as you then need to wrap it once more.